# Как сохранить полученные данные из JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Имеется код, который получает json при помощи XMLHttpRequest. Полученные данные сохраняются в переменную loadedData при вызове соответствующего слушателя.

Возможно ли записать полученный объект в переменную data?

```js
var URL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';

var data;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'json';


  var xhrLoadHandler = function() {
    var loadedData = xhr.response;
  }

  xhr.addEventListener('load', xhrLoadHandler);

  xhr.open('GET', URL);
  xhr.send();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваш XML-HTTP запрос настроен как асинхронный (Скрипт не дожидается ответа от сервера и продолжает выполнятся).

Это означает, что когда будет получен ответ от сервера, переменная `data` уже не будет существовать.

Измените `xhr.open('GET', URL);` на `xhr.open('GET', URL, false);` чтобы запрос был синхронным (Скрипт не будет выполнятся дальше, пока не получит ответ от сервера).

```js
var URL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';

var data;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var xhrLoadHandler = function() {
     data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
};

xhr.addEventListener('load', xhrLoadHandler);

xhr.open('GET', URL, false);
xhr.send();
```